# python pandas loops to melt or pivot multiple df

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pivot, melt

I have several df with the same structure. I'd like to create a loop to melt them or create a pivot table.

I tried the following but are not working

```py
my_df = [df1, df2, df3]

for df in my_df:
   df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C'], value_name = 'my_value')

for df in my_df:
   df = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'my_value', index = ['A','B','C'], columns = ['my_column'])
```

Any help would be great. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need assign output to new list of `DataFrame`s:

```
out = []
for df in my_df:
   df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C'], value_name = 'my_value')
   out.append(df)
```

Same idea in list comprehension:

```
out = [pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C'], value_name = 'my_value') for df in my_df]
```

If need overwitten origional values in list:

```
for i, df in enumerate(my_df):
   df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C'], value_name = 'my_value')
   my_df[i] = df

print (my_df)
```

If need overwrite variables `df1, df2, df3`:

```
df1, df2, df3 = [pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A','B','C'], value_name = 'my_value') for df in my_df]
```

Comment: Thank you. What should I do if I want to keep df1, df2, df3 separate? Basically have three ouputs.

Comment: @Matteo - Do you think output should be `[df1, df2, df3]` with melted data?

Comment: @Matteo - So original data should be lost and overwitten?

Comment: Yes original data should be lost and overwitten

Comment: @Matteo - I think you can overwotten only list, `df1-df3` should be overitten by last solution.

Comment: Thank you. The last solution (overwrite variables df1, df2, df3) is exactly what I needed.